# How to build scope query?

Tags: content-search

I have a scope query that retrieves all items that contain `includedinsearch` field with value `searchable` but I also need it to exclude an item when this item has `EndDate` or `EventEnd` field with values earlier than today.

example query:

```
custom:includedinsearch|"searchable";custom:EndDate|[NOW/DAY TO *];custom:EventEnd|[NOW/DAY TO *]
```

[image]

Comment: What is your search provider? And if Solr - what is that actual problem?

Comment: yes, it's Solr. the problem is I have some items -of different templates- that have a filed called "includedinsearch" with the value "searchable" but some of these items have "EndDate" field and some others have "EventEnd" field and some templates dont have either of these 2 fields. I just want the query to include the date fields in case they exist in the template, and in case they do, validate that the date is after today.